# angularjs bind to controller with isolated scope

Tags: angularjs

I have a pretty simple directive and I want to use the **bindToController** option. So, I created my directive like this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('sapphire.directives').directive('list', list);

    function list() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            template: '<div class="row flex-column" ng-class="{ \'spinner-dark\': controller.loading }" ng-include="controller.templateUrl" ng-if="controller.loading || controller.models.length"></div>',
            controller: 'ListDirectiveController',
            controllerAs: 'controller',
            scope: true,
            bindToController: {
                method: '&list',
                templateName: '@'
            }
        };
    };
})();
```

And then I created my controller like this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('sapphire.directives').controller('ListDirectiveController', listDirectiveController);

    listDirectiveController.$inject = ['ListDirectiveService', 'Selections'];

    function listDirectiveController(broadcast, selections) {
        var self = this;

        console.log(self);

        // Bindings
        self.limit = 0;
        self.total = 0;
        self.loading = true;
        self.templateUrl = 'app/directives/lists/list/' + (self.templateName || 'list-default') + '.html';
        self.isSelected = selections.isSelected;
        self.select = selections.select;

        // Method binding
        self.list = list;

        init();

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////

        function init() {
            list();
        };

        // Our list method
        function list() {

            // Set our initial limit
            self.limit += 10;
            self.loading = true;

            // Get our items
            return self.method({ limit: self.limit }).then(function (response) {
                self.loading = false;
                self.models = response;
                self.total = response.length;
            });
        };

        ///////// ------ Removed for brevity ------ /////////
    };
})();
```

When I use this directive I get an error stating:

> self.method is not a function

which is why I am console.logging the controller to see what is bound to it. Surely enough, the **method** and **templateName** are missing.
I have tried a few ways to get this to work:

```
scope: {
    method: '&list',
    templateName: '@'
},
bindToController: true
```

or

```
scope: {},
bindToController: {
    method: '&list',
    templateName: '@'
}
```

but nothing seems to work. I can't get my isolated scope to be bound to my controller....
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

PS: I am using angular 1.6.4

To use the directive I do this:

```
<div class="invisible-container" list="controller.listUsers(limit)" template-name="users"></div>
```

Comment: where did you used this directive? post that part of code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured this out. The scope is bound, but it isn't available straight away. I had to create an **init** method and invoke it from the directive. Only then was everything bound.
I did it like this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('sapphire.directives').directive('list', list);

    function list() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            template: '<div class="row flex-column" ng-class="{ \'spinner-dark\': controller.loading }" ng-include="controller.templateUrl" ng-if="controller.loading || controller.models.length"></div>',
            controller: 'ListDirectiveController',
            controllerAs: 'controller',
            scope: {
                method: '&list',
                templateName: '@'
            },
            bindToController: true,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                controller.init();
            }
        };
    };
})();
```

and the controller now looks like this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('sapphire.directives').controller('ListDirectiveController', listDirectiveController);

    listDirectiveController.$inject = ['ListDirectiveService', 'Selections'];

    function listDirectiveController(broadcast, selections) {
        var self = this;

        // Bindings
        self.limit = 0;
        self.total = 0;
        self.loading = true;
        self.isSelected = selections.isSelected;
        self.select = selections.select;

        // Method binding
        self.init = init;

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        function init() {
            list();
            getTemplate();
            bindEvents();
        };

        function bindEvents() {
            broadcast.onPrepend(onPrepend);
            broadcast.onRefresh(onRefresh);
        };

        function getTemplate() {
            self.templateUrl = 'app/directives/lists/list/' + (self.templateName || 'list-default') + '.html';
        };

        function list() {

            // Set our initial limit
            self.limit += 10;
            self.loading = true;

            // Get our items
            return self.method({ limit: self.limit }).then(function (response) {
                self.loading = false;
                self.models = response;
                self.total = response.length;
            });
        };

        function onPrepend(event, args) {
            if (args && args.target && args.target === self.templateName) {
                self.models.unshift(args.model);
            }
        };

        function onRefresh(event, args) {
            if (args && args.target && args.target === self.templateName) {
                self.limit -= 10;
                self.models = [];
                list();
            }
        };
    };
})();
```